# Magento 2 How to set product minimum quantity selected to minimum qty configured in the Advanced Inventory product level

Tags: magento2, catalog, quantity, cataloginventory

If 5 is the minimum Qty on Advanced Inventory product level for a product then in Product detail page it should as 5 default selected.

How can I achieve this.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

> **go to** Catalog > Inventory > Product Stock Options.

[image]

> In **Product Stock Options**, find 2 sections: **Maximum Qty Allowed** in
>   Shopping Cart and **Minimum Qty Allowed** in Shopping Cart.

[image]

In **Maximum Qty Allowed** in Shopping Cart, enter a number to determine the maximum quantity for products added to cart.

In **Minimum Qty Allowed** in Shopping Cart, pick customer group and assign the minimum order quantity to that group.

> app/code/Vendor/Module/Block/getQty.php

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Block;
class getQty extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{    
    protected $_stockItemRepository;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,        
        \Magento\CatalogInventory\Model\Stock\StockItemRepository $stockItemRepository,
        array $data = []
    )
    {
        $this->_stockItemRepository = $stockItemRepository;
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }

    public function getStockItem($productId)
    {
        return $this->_stockItemRepository->get($productId);
    }
}
?>
```

**in template file**

```
$id = 123;
$_productStock = $block->getStockItem($id);
$_productStock->getMinSaleQty();
```

> app/design/frontend/default/YourTheme/template/catalog/product/list.phtml

```
<button type="button" title="<?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?>" onclick="setLocation('<?php echo $this->getAddToCartUrl($_product) ?>')"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?></span></span></button>
And just replace it with,

<form action="<?php echo $this->getAddToCartUrl($_product) ?>" method="post" id="product_addtocart_form_<?php echo $_product->getId()?>"<?php if($_product->getOptions()): ?> enctype="multipart/form-data"<?php endif; ?>>
<?php if(!$_product->isGrouped()): ?>
<label for="qty"><?php echo $this->__('Qty') ?>:</label>
<input type="text" name="qty" id="qty" maxlength="12" value="<?php echo ($this->getMinimalQty($_product)?$this->getMinimalQty($_product):1) ?>" />
<?php endif; ?>
<button type="button" onclick="this.form.submit()"><span><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?></span></span></span></button>
</form>
```

Comment: I need it for product level so Catalog >> Products >> under  Quantity Advanced Inventory I have provided the value but when I go to detail page its showing as 1 and not as 5 default selected I need to have the default Minimum Qty value  selected in the QTY

Comment: for particular product

Comment: Admin >> Catalog >> Product >> Open product which you want to add >> Inventory >> Minimum Qty Allowed in Shopping Cart.

Comment: and after that please flush the cache

Comment: Yes I did but it still shows 1 and not 5

Comment: okay, got your issue.

Comment: Please click on "add to cart" with 1 qty

Comment: You can see the image I have attached showing You can buy this product only in quantities of 5 at a time. The functionality works perfect but I need the Qty box to be 5 on loading into the page,

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/84181/discussion-between-aditya-shah-and-fernandus).

Comment: When the page is loaded it shows 1 in Qty box i need it to be 5 that is the minimum qty selected in Advanced Inventory product level